# Could not open location 'network://'

Tags: networking

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.  I am getting the following error when I click on Network:

> Could not open location 'network://'
>
> DBus error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.